# What sort of graph of Vout/Vin vs frequency will a low-pass and high pass filters have?

Tags: filter, low-pass

The graphic is in log (Vout/Vin) vs log (f).
I think that, for the first one, would be something like this: http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/logs/log4/log42/gl02.gif and for the second one will be the opposite, that is, starting positive and going negative. Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's the other way around:

[image]
[image]

These are from the http://manual.audacityteam.org/, which you could actually use to experiment to see how they sound without having to build anything.

Comment: You'll probably want to read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel too.

Comment: Clear answer, +1. However, this is a good opportunity to do the EE world a service and not use the term "cutoff frequency".  I have run into beginners enough times that think a resistor and capacitor make a brick wall filter.  After all, one side is past the cut off, right?  I'm careful to use the term "rolloff frequency" instead.  Those that understand this will know exactly what you mean, but beginners won't get the wrong impression.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Yes, that's a good point regarding the potential for confusion... but the terminology is [unfortunately established](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency).

Comment: Thank you. You did what my teacher couldn't, that is, explain me this. Thank you, dude :)

Comment: @Resp: There are lots of bad practises out there in the world.  While individuals may not be able to get them changed, they can at least not perpetuate them.  Making a point to say "rolloff frequency" instead of "cutoff frequency" is basically free.  For a long time people objected to milli-Farads and nano-Farads too, but enough people used them and refused to conform to the established "standard" so that now they are acceptable.  All I'm asking is to not continue to be part of the problem.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I actually prefer to use "corner frequency" myself because it has a [geometric meaning](http://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/corner-frequency.png)... but I couldn't find a pair of matching graphs in my lazy google images search.

Answer (score 1):

For a filter, given the transfer function, you must read about [Bode plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot).
This sort of graphic is "standard" for frequency response.

Comment: What is that? My teacher never told us that. He just asked us this question and I'm trying to find out a graphic for log (Vout//Vin) vs log (f)

Comment: @RobertoSousa You have read the information on the link? is just about graphics function of frequency, on a logarithmic scale.

Comment: just to make sure I understood. IN high pass filters, the log graphic will be from negative to around 0 and in low pass filters from around 0 to negative, correct?

Why is that?

Comment: @RobertoSousa That describes a "passive filter". In the case of a low-pass, the gain is zero at low frequencies and at high frequencies, attenuation occurs. The attenuation, expressed in dB, takes negative values. In an "active filter" the gain can be different from zero in the passband.